# How do I generate a crosswalk ID between two SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table consisting of names, addresses and some associated numerical data paired with a code. The table is structured such that each number-code pair has its own row with redundant address info. abbreviated version below, let's call it `tblPeopleData`

```
Name            Address                       ArbitraryCode    ArbitraryData
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                111
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                231
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                123
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            b                111
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            c                111
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            d                123
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            d                124
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                111
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                231
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                123
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              b                111
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              c                111
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              e                123
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              e                124
```

My problem is that this table is absolutely massive (~10 million rows) and I'm trying to split it up to make traversal less staggeringly sluggish.

What I've done so far is to make a table of just addresses, using something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Address FROM tblPeopleData (etc.)
```

Leaving me with:

```
Name            Address                       
------------------------------------------
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY      
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL
```

...just a list of addresses. I want to be able to look up each address and see which names reside at that address, so I assigned each address a UniqueID, such that now I have (this table is around ~500,000 rows in my dataset):

```
Name            Address                       AddressID
--------------------------------------------------------
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY      000001
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL        000002
```

In order to be able to look up people by address though, I need this AddressID field added to tblPeopleData, such that each address in tblPeopleData is associated with its AddressID and this is added to every row, such that I would have:

```
Name            Address                       ArbitraryCode    ArbitraryData    AddressID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                111          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                231          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            a                123          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            b                111          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            c                111          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            d                123          00001
John Adams      45 Main St, Rochester NY            d                124          00001
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                111          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                231          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              a                123          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              b                111          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              c                111          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              e                123          00002
Jane McArthur   12 1st Ave, Chicago IL              e                124          00002
```

How do I make this jump from having UniqueIDs for AddressID in my unique addresses table, to adding these all to each row with a corresponding address back in my `tbPeopleData`?

Comment: You need three tables here. One for Name, another for address and a third for the arbitrary data. The name table would have a foreign key to the address table and the arbitrary data table would have a foreign key to the name/people table.

Comment: I could try this. There is actually already a pre-existing unique ID that binds ArbitraryData and Person, so I could split it up without much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just backfill the calculated AddressID back to `tblPeopleData` - you can combine an `UPDATE` with a `FROM` (like you would do in a select)

```
UPDATE tblPeopleData 
SET AddressID = a.AddressID
FROM tblPeopleData pd
INNER JOIN tblAddressData a
 ON pd.Address = a.Address
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me perfectly. Additionally, since I was dealing with ~10 million rows and the query took a long time, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754632/962986) was incredibly helpful for tracking progress.

Answer (score 1):

You would alter the table to have the address id:

```
alter table tblPeopleData add AddressId int references Address(AddressId);
```

Then you can update the value using a `JOIN`:

```
update tblPeopleData pd JOIN
       Address a
       ON pd.Address = a.Address
    pd.AddressId = a.AddressId;
```

You will definitely want an index on `Address(Address)` for this.

Then, you can drop the old column:

```
alter table drop column Address;
```

Note:

It might be faster to save the results in a temporary table, because the update is going to generate lots and lots of log records.  For this, truncate the original table, and re-load the data:

```
SELECT . . . , a.AddressId
INTO tmp_tblPeopleData
FROM tblPeopleData pd JOIN
     Address a
     ON pd.Address = a.Address;

TRUNCATE TABLE tblPeopleData;

INSERT INTO tblPeopleData( . . .)
    SELECT . . .
    FROM tmp_tblPeopleData;
```